# package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready, but what do the properties mean?

Tags: git, heroku, meteor, bcrypt, node-pre-gyp

I want to deploy an app to heroku. A while ago it was working, but when I tried to push, now it gives me "Push rejected".

I tried to run node-pre-gyp install and it tells me that my package.json is not node-pre-gyp ready, telling me that:

package.json must declare these properties:

main

version

binary.module_name

binary.module_path

binary.host

It seems like this is the problem, however, I'm quite new to web developing (this is my first project) and I have no idea what these properties mean so I don't know how to add them in my package.json.

```sh
heroku login
git add .
git commit -m "test"
git push heroku master
```

This is how I usually deploy the code.

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "8.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "meteor run",
    "test": "meteor test --once --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "test-app": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --full-app --driver-package meteortesting:mocha",
    "visualize": "meteor --production --extra-packages bundle-visualizer"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.0",
    "bcrypt": "^3.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.4.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "0.13.0"
  },
  "meteor": {
    "mainModule": {
      "client": "client/main.js",
      "server": "server/main.js"
    },
    "testModule": "tests/main.js"
  }
}
```

This is my package.json.

```
remote: regexpu-core@4.4.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regexpu-core
remote: regenerate@1.4.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regenerate
remote: regenerate-unicode-properties@7.0.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regenerate-unicode-properties
remote: regjsgen@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regjsgen
remote: regjsparser@0.6.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regjsparser
remote: jsesc@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regjsparser/node_modules/jsesc
remote: unicode-match-property-ecmascript@1.0.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/unicode-match-property-ecmascript
remote: unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript@1.0.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/unicode-canonical-property-names-ecmascript
remote: unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript@1.0.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/unicode-property-aliases-ecmascript
remote: unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript@1.0.2 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/unicode-match-property-value-ecmascript
remote: @babel/preset-react@7.0.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/preset-react
remote: @babel/runtime@7.3.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/@babel/runtime
remote: regenerator-runtime@0.12.1 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/regenerator-runtime
remote: acorn@5.7.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/acorn
remote: babel-helper-evaluate-path@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-evaluate-path
remote: babel-helper-flip-expressions@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-flip-expressions
remote: babel-helper-is-nodes-equiv@0.0.1 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-is-nodes-equiv
remote: babel-helper-is-void-0@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-is-void-0
remote: babel-helper-mark-eval-scopes@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-mark-eval-scopes
remote: babel-helper-remove-or-void@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-remove-or-void
remote: babel-helper-to-multiple-sequence-expressions@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-helper-to-multiple-sequence-expressions
remote: babel-plugin-minify-builtins@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-builtins
remote: babel-plugin-minify-constant-folding@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-constant-folding
remote: babel-plugin-minify-dead-code-elimination@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-dead-code-elimination
remote: lodash.some@4.6.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/lodash.some
remote: babel-plugin-minify-flip-comparisons@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-flip-comparisons
remote: babel-plugin-minify-guarded-expressions@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-guarded-expressions
remote: babel-plugin-minify-infinity@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-infinity
remote: babel-plugin-minify-mangle-names@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-mangle-names
remote: babel-plugin-minify-numeric-literals@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-numeric-literals
remote: babel-plugin-minify-replace@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-replace
remote: babel-plugin-minify-simplify@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-simplify
remote: babel-plugin-minify-type-constructors@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-minify-type-constructors
remote: babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-reify@0.18.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-reify
remote: reify@0.18.1 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-reify/node_modules/reify
remote: babel-plugin-transform-inline-consecutive-adds@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-inline-consecutive-adds
remote: babel-plugin-transform-member-expression-literals@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-member-expression-literals
remote: babel-plugin-transform-merge-sibling-variables@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-merge-sibling-variables
remote: babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans
remote: babel-plugin-transform-property-literals@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-property-literals
remote: babel-plugin-transform-regexp-constructors@0.4.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-regexp-constructors
remote: babel-plugin-transform-remove-console@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-remove-console
remote: babel-plugin-transform-remove-debugger@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-remove-debugger
remote: babel-plugin-transform-remove-undefined@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-remove-undefined
remote: babel-plugin-transform-simplify-comparison-operators@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-simplify-comparison-operators
remote: babel-plugin-transform-undefined-to-void@6.9.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-undefined-to-void
remote: babel-preset-meteor@7.3.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-preset-meteor
remote: babel-preset-minify@0.5.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/babel-preset-minify
remote: lodash.isplainobject@4.0.6 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/lodash.isplainobject
remote: json5@2.1.0 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/json5
remote: meteor-babel@7.3.4 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel
remote: meteor-babel-helpers@0.0.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel-helpers
remote: reify@0.17.3 /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/reify
remote: 
remote: > bcrypt@3.0.0 install /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
remote: > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote: 
remote: node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.0 and node@8.15.1 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
remote: node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error Remote end closed socket abruptly. 
remote: node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.0 and node@8.15.1 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
remote: node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error bad download 
remote: make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
remote: make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
remote:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
remote:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o
remote: rm: cannot remove './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o.d.raw': No such file or directory
remote: bcrypt_lib.target.mk:103: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o' failed
remote: make: *** [Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/blowfish.o] Error 1
remote: make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/build'
remote:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bcrypt_lib/src/bcrypt.o
remote: gyp ERR! build error 
remote: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
remote: gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote: gyp ERR! command "/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node" "--module_name=bcrypt_lib" "--module_path=/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi"
remote: gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
remote: gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
remote: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
remote: gyp ERR! not ok 
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:915:16)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node" "/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v8.15.1
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.2
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
remote: Failed to execute '/app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node /app/tmp/cache/meteor/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.1.1sak1mc.c14s++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node --module_name=bcrypt_lib --module_path=/tmp/build_be7761c4e5b001e1b5dbfe1536cb4eec/.meteor/heroku_build/app/programs/server/npm/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.0 install script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-09-08T15_17_16_793Z-debug.log
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! errno 1
remote: npm ERR! meteor-dev-bundle@ install: `node npm-rebuild.js`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the meteor-dev-bundle@ install script.
remote: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-09-08T15_17_16_852Z-debug.log
remote: make: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
remote: make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
remote: make: *** wait: No child processes.  Stop.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to frozenfruits.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/frozenfruits.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/frozenfruits.git'
```

This is the error log when I run git push heroku master.

Comment: "now it gives me "Push rejected"... I tried to run node-pre-gyp install"—why do you think running `node-pre-gyp install` is the solution? What's the full error message?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post the error message. This is the part that mentions node-pre-gyp:

remote: npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`

remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1

by the way, how do I edit the post?

Comment: You can edit your question with the [edit] link to the lower-left of your question. Please include as much relevant context as you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working backwards from the error, the key lines in the error log are:

```
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.0 install script.
```

Which tells us that bcrypt's install script is the culprit (not your app code)

```
remote: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
```

Which shows an error when `node-gyp` was running `make` which is used to compile native addons to node.
and:

```
remote: node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for bcrypt@3.0.0 and node@8.15.1 (node-v57 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
```

Which tells us that `node-pre-gyp` initially tried to download a pre-built version of bcrypt to save you the hassle of compilation, but failed because there's isn't a pre-built version of bcrypt 3 for node 8.

This means that if we find a version of bcrypt that works for the node version, we should be good!
The [version compatibility table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt#version-compatibility) tells us:

```
| Node Version | bcrypt Version | 
| ------------ |:--------------:|
|      8       |    >= 1.0.3    |
|    10, 11    |      >= 3      |
```

So you want a version of bcrypt between 1.0.3 and 3.0.0.

Looking at the versions tab on npm, we see the latest version that fits is `2.0.1`

So you want to change the version in your `package.json` to 2.0.1:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^2.0.1",
    ... etc
```

While you're at it, you should probably remove `bcryptjs` if you're using `bcrypt`, and `node-pre-gyp`, as it's very unlikely your actual application is using that in production

In fact, that'd be why `node-pre-gyp install` is telling you that you're not "node-pre-gyp ready", just remove `node-pre-gyp`

Comment: Hopefully you learned something about debugging at the same time as solving your problem!